# Is there a positive displacement pump that experiences only rolling resistance?

Tags: pumps, friction, rolling

Is there a positive displacement pump that experiences only rolling resistance? One with no sliding friction and diaphragm stretching?

Comment: Are you thinking of a peristaltic pump?

Comment: the flexing of the "hose" is esentially equivalent to streching of a diaphragm

Comment: peristalic pumps also have frictional losses besides ones at the bearings of the rollers - the deformation of the tube doesn't give back all the energy you put into it

Comment: @FrancisL.  The flexing of the hose is it being crushed, not stretched.

Comment: @PeteW so what do you suggest? Axial, centrifugal? Piston? Mercury?

Comment: You need to provide the application. What rpm, pressure, flow rate, fluid, temperature range, and operating environment. There are some, but they don't cover all applications.

Comment: Rolamite - It took a minute for the right brain cell to remember this one:) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolamite

Comment: @Solar Mike - depends on the application. I use Peri pumps a lot, good control in closed loop and hard to beat when clean/sterile is needed. But low friction, they're not.

Comment: a gear pump doesn't "slide"

Comment: yeah gear pump or lobe pump sounds closest. At least in the 2D section....  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Three_lobe_Roots_blower_animation.webm

Answer (score 3):

Rolling diphragms have been around for many years now. See...
https://www.diacom.com/rolling-diaphragm-theory

[image: rolling diaphragm]

With or without the spring.

(With enough vacuum in the top you can get the membrane to slip upwards, but it is easily reset by cycling.)

Fabric reinforcement helps prevent stretch, but generally everything is elastic to some extent.

Additionally, https://www.airpot.com/ has made some innovative low friction graphite/glass piston/tube cylinders that I haven't tried with fluids other than air.

[image: airpot dashpot]

Answer (score 1):

Our body has several examples, our throat when swallowing, our  intestines would be another example.

Arteries in our legs pump the blood by our leg muscles squeezing them.

Comment: Isn’t the swallowing action peristalsis? Which is why peristaltic pumps were discussed above. Or you missed the comments.

Comment: @Solar Mike, i stand by mu answer. Swallowing and pushing the food down the intestines is done by rolling action, no rotating or spinning, or difragms involved.

Answer (score 1):

Progressing cavity pumps. The rotor executes a rolling motion in the stator, because of the different auger like shapes of rotor and stator the cavity between moves along the axis. [This video shows the movement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNOPjkz4Rc0).